# How to completely (I mean COMPLETELY) destroy all session data and prevent cached access?

Tags: php, session

I am currently setting up a website using a pay-wall type backend that you log into with Microsoft accounts. Currently, I am using PHP sessions to capture and track valid requests.

I have managed to completely destroy all session data saved on the server as well as rename and blank the session cookies (See code below). Unfortunately, this is not enough it seems. I can still access the page by passing the old session ID through GET variable and I can still load the page. I suspect it is a cached version. I have tried adding in php headders to prevent this but its still loading!

### Log out code:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
    session_start($_POST["SID"]);
    $_SESSION[] = array();

    setcookie( session_name(), "", time()-3600, "/" );

    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    echo("Session ".$_POST["SID"]." has been destroyed");
}
?>
```

### Header code:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

I was expecting to be able to hit the log out button and if I tried to manually access the page by supplying the old session id by GET command, I should have been bounced by the page. Is there any way to get around this? Maybe force the page to re-query the server (if I can just get it to ping the server again I believe my php should bounce the request? *I say that with some hesitance hahaha*)

**EDIT:**

Ok, so after a whole lot of debugging, I have narrowed the problem down too my `$_SESSION["IS_AUTHORIZED"]` variable? This shouldn't be possible but somehow, the standalone PHP script I wrote to destroy a session when the user logs out, can run the same `session_id()`, but somehow cannot access any of the session variables?! if I `var_dump($_SESSION["IS_AUTHORIZED"])`, it spits out `NULL`, whereas on all the other pages, it spits out the Boolean `0` or `1`?!?!?! I am very confused... I guess this is why I cant properly remove the session?

**Code:**

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    session_id($_POST["SID"]);
    echo(session_id()); //comes out as same as session origin page
    session_start();
    echo("|||"); //to make payoad easier to read lol
    echo($_SESSION["IS_AUTHORIZED"]); //nothing... and var_dump() is NULL?
?>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Oh lord. So now after some tinkering the stand-alone PHP script works and links up to the correct `session_id()` and I can do the whole `session_destroy()`, `$_SESSION = array();` bit to clear the session info. Small problem though, if I refresh the HTML page with the `session_id()` as a GET variable, it still loads the page? Even says the `$_SESSION["IS_AUTHORIZED"] variable I supposedly just cleared in my stand-alone script is now back and reverted to before I cleared it? That literally defeats the entire point of using sessions? help please! ( I HATE php sessions so far oh my soul!)

Comment: do you store a reference to the session in the db at any point?

Comment: Nope. Only storing user data like name, surname, email etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Just posting for anyone else who has this issue.

Turns out it all linked back to the `session_write_close()` command. In my HTML page which hosted restricted content, I had PHP code which checked session variables to determine weather or not to show the page or redirect. Obviously in order to access the `$_SESSION[]` variables in the first place I first had to set `session_id($_GET[<session id passed via GET>])`, and then do the checking. Unfortunately, I never called `session_write_close()` so that webpage never disconnected from the session file. My stand-alone logout script WAS actually deleting the `$_SESSION` and `unset($_SESSION[<variable name>])` WAS working. The issue is that upon the HTML page refresh, I guess it re-saved the session file all over again and effectively re-created it.

The easiest analogy I could think of to explain it would be, editing a Word document and deleting the actual file while it was open in Word, then saving from Word, effectively re-creating the document all over again.

It took me changing the save directory to where I could access it and actually monitoring how the session file changed to figure it out (Good debugging technique btw)

Hope this helps future PHP coders (Good luck, you'll need it lol)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  session_start() ;
  unset($_SESSION["IS_AUTHORIZED"]);
  session_destroy();
  session_write_close();
  $_SESSION=new array();
  session_regenerate_id(true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Destroy the session data file located in `session_save_path()` folder / `session.save_path` directive.

Comment: ok, so not really sure how to do that. Did however manage to narrow the problem down. It seems like the session variable I am using (`$_SESSION["IS_AUTHORIZED"]`  to track logins and logouts simply refuses to be changed or erased by my logout script. If I try and access the page with the session ID, `echo`'ing the `#_SESSION["IS_AUTHORIZED"]`, it still comes up as 1 A.k.a. true?